# Datalist itemcommand design?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am using datalist to display the images, i put properties of repeatcolumn=4 and reapeatdirection=horizontal. It is displaying good when there r more than or 4 images if there r only one or two or three images the gap between images r too long. if i have only one image the image displayed in datalist in the middle of the datalist. how can i solve this problem. i think you people understand my problem this is my datalist source code... datalist width="100%"

```
<asp:DataList ID ="dtlstallfrind" RepeatColumns ="4" RepeatDirection="horizontal"widht=100> 

    <ItemTemplate >

          <table width="100%" >

            <tr>
               <td  >

                  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgeFrien" runat ="Server" Width="110px" Height ="100px" CommandName ="Image" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("userid") %>' ImageUrl ='<%# "~/Userimages/"+ Eval("myimage") %>' />
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td >
                  <asp:Label ID="lblFrieNam" runat ="Server" Font-Names ="verdana"  Text ='<%# Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label> 
               </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you try this?

```
<ItemTemplate >   

    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgeFrien" runat ="Server" Width="110px" Height ="100px" 
        CommandName ="Image" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("userid") %>' ImageUrl ='<%# 
        "~/Userimages/"+ Eval("myimage") %>' />

    <asp:Label ID="lblFrieNam" runat ="Server" Font-Names ="verdana"  Text ='<%# 
         Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label> 

</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: no Mr.steve it is displaying same, the user name coming beside the image.

Comment: If you set a width for the Datalist, unset it.  A Datalist renders a table.  If the table has a fixed with, the cells will expand to the width. Can you post the whole datalist code?

Comment: If you float the image right, the text will be underneath the image.

Comment: ya its working fine i remove width of the datlist and it is working fine thank you Mr.Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RepeatLayout="Flow" ItemStyle="float:left;"` and see what happens... Let me know what it does?

Comment: ok i will try and inform u. now i am going for lunch i will reply within 50mn ok thank you for response

Comment: Mr. Pandiya Chendur  when i type ItemStyle under this it is showing greenmark saying it is not valid attribute and the images coming vertically

Comment: in itemstyle tag i not found any float:left when i place it is giving error in the page

Comment: @sasidar use css `.urclass{float:left;} in css` and include CssClass Name in `<itemstyle>` as `<ItemStyle CssClass="urclass">`

Comment: no Mr.Pandiya Chendur the images or displaying with gap t his is my code

<asp:DataList ID ="dtlstallfrind"    RepeatColumns ="4" RepeatLayout ="flow"RepeatDirection ="horizontal"  runat ="Server" Width="100%" >
                   <ItemStyle CssClass ="urclass" />
                  <ItemTemplate >

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow

Comment: ya just now i place my images it comes like this only

Comment: yes if there 4 images the images r correct format if below 4 or 3 the images look like above image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449344/asp-net-datalist-defining-columns-rows-when-repeating-horizontal-and-using-fl